# Web deploy package doesn't include database

Tags: visual-studio, iis, webdeploy

When I publish via web deploy directly from Visual Studio into IIS, the databases I configured in the project package/Publish SQL are deployed the SQL Server.

However, when I publish a `Web Deploy Package` from the same project, the package does not appear to include the the database and does not deploy any db to SQL Server when either imported into IIS or when the package .cmd is run.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution?  Which version of Visual Studio are you using?